# two-step authentication

Tags: joomla-3.x

To access the administration of the site ( https://philosciences.com/administrator/), I have a two-step authentication procedure set up several years ago.

A first authentication of the type: The [site](https://philosciences.com) asks for a username and a password. The site says: "Restricted Area"
It provides access to the classic Joomla authentication that asks for login and password.
I would like to modify the first authentication but I forgot the procedure.

I specify that it is not a double authentication by google or by Ubikey but a simple doubling of the procedure.

Does anyone know how to access, and how to modify, this pre-authentication?

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Modify what exactly? You haven't specified the authentication, who developed it, which 3rd party service it is. We need more information about it before being able to help.

Answer (score 1):

On Apache servers, a common method (and hopefully the method used on the OP website) to add an extra layer of security to the Joomla back-end is to specify an additional username and password via `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files in the `/administrator` folder.

The free or paid version of [Akeeba Admin Tools has a tool that can help set this up](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/admin-tools/admin-pw-protection.html).

Alternatively, you can find instructions at: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection

To disable this additional security layer, rename `/administrator/.htaccess` to `/administrator/.htaccess.old` or similar.